# What is known about 2nd order estimation biases due to correlated noise between response variables?

Tags: correlation, estimation, bias, noise

I have recently run into a statistical bias in a type of analysis that I believe is somewhat common in my field, and not typically corrected for. I would like to know if this is more well-known in other fields or in statistics in general, and whether it has a standard name or solution (I have a solution but I wonder if this is the standard one, and if it is, I'd like to have a reference for it).

The bias arises when estimating the mean of, or fitting models to, data with noise that is correlated **between response variables**. I want to stress that I am *not* talking about correlated noise between measurements of the same variable, which seems to be a more widely known and discussed phenomenon (e.g. when doing a linear regression this would violate the assumption of independence between residuals).

To make it more concrete, suppose we have some data that obeys the following model:
$$
Y = F(X)+\Gamma
$$
where $Y$, $F(X)$ and $\Gamma$ are $N\times M$ matrices, where $N$ is the number of (simultaneously measured) observations and $M$ the number of response variables. $Y$ are the observations of the response variables, $F(X)$ is some function of the independent variables, and $\Gamma$ is Normally distributed noise with, covariance $\Sigma\in\Re^{M\times M}$ between response variables (i.e. between columns of $\Gamma$).

The goal of the analysis is to estimate $F(X)$, which we won't specify any further because I want to keep the statement of the problem quite general, but you could imagine this being a linear regression model, or even just a simple mean. Since $E[\Gamma]=0$, the least-squares estimate of $F(X)$ is unbiased in the first order, i.e. $E[\hat{F(X)}]=F(X)$. However, because noise is correlated between response variables, $E[\frac{1}{N}\Gamma^T\Gamma]=\Sigma\neq0$, and therefore the covariance between the estimates $\hat{F(X)}$ is not unbiased, but will instead be proportional to the noise covariance $\Sigma$:
$$
E[\hat{F(X)}^T\hat{F(X)}]-F(X)^TF(X)\propto\Sigma
$$
This is a problem if you want to test the hypothesis that $E[{F(X)}^T{F(X)}]\propto\Sigma$, which happens to be a common hypothesis in my field, because your analysis is biased to find this hypothesized relationship in the estimates of $F(X)$, even if it doesn't exist in reality. That is, you are biased to find estimates of $F(X)$ that are similar between response variables with correlated noise, even if the true similarity structure of $F(X)$ does not mimic the noise correlation structure.

The simple solution that I've come up with is to divide the data into independent halves $Y^{(1)}$ & $Y^{(2)}$, compute separate estimates $\hat{F(X)}^{(1)}$ & $\hat{F(X)}^{(2)}$ from these data partitions, and then calculate the covariance between those independent estimates. Since noise is independent by construction between $Y^{(1)}$ & $Y^{(2)}$, this means that the bias has disappeared, i.e. we know have $$E[{\hat{F(X)}^{(1)}}^T{\hat{F(X)}^{(2)}}]=F(X)^TF(X)$$

Does any of this ring familiar to anyone here? I would like to know if what I'm describing is a well known issue with a standard solution (which I feel it ought to be), and would appreciate any references to literature on this.